# template_from_string twig not return html

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to use twig extension as shortcodes in symfony. I did that {{ function() }} read from database from ckeditore saved content in table, but problem is that function load all querys, etc. but if i render it to view it gives me a string, escaped a html tags. any sugestion how to say to twig template that i need to render a html tags from function ?

code i used:

display content from database used function of twig:

```
{% extends 'front/base.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
 <div class="container">


  {{include(template_from_string(content|raw))}}


 </div>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

in twig extension i got:

```
public function getPagesName()
{

  $pages = $this->em
  ->getRepository(Pages::class)
  ->findAll();

  $pagesnames = array();
  foreach($pages as $page)
  {
    $name = $page->getJson();
    $name = $name['title'];
    dump($name);
    array_push($pagesnames, $name);
  }

  $template = $this->env->render('front\test.html.twig', ['pagesnames' => $pagesnames]);
  return $template;

}
```

and in test.html.twig i got:

```
<ul>
  {% for name in pagesnames %}
    <li>{{name}} - strona</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and the result in index is:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="container">


  <p>&lt;ul&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Strona główna - strona&lt;/li&gt;
      &lt;li&gt;Testowa strona - strona&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;/ul&gt;
 - czyste wariatctwo</p>



 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: should be a html format, not string in <p>

Comment: Instead of `include`, use `source`?

Comment: nope, got this `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Twig\TemplateWrapper could not be converted to string").`

Comment: any idea how to solve it ?